# Show loader when button is clicked in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, loader

I'm trying to implement the loader animation in my react native app but it does't trigger the loader when the button is clicked, although the animating already change to `true`.

Check out my code below.

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.hideLoader();
}

showLoader = () => { this.setState({ showLoader:true }); };
hideLoader = () => { this.setState({ showLoader:false }); };

doSignup = () => {
    this.showLoader();
}

render() {
    console.log(this.state.showLoader);
    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 25 }} onPress={this.doSignup}>
              <View style={[ styles.button, { backgroundColor: '#5a0060' } ]}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white }}>Sign Up Now</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <View style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0, left: 0 }}>
              <ActivityIndicator animating={this.state.showLoader} size="small" color="#00ff00" />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

When the screen is loaded, I set the loader animation as `false`. When the button is clicked only set to `true` which should be able to animate the loader but it doesn't appear.

Comment: does the animation works if you set the state manually to true in debugger?

Comment: @gazdagergo Yes it's showing if I set it `true` by default.

Answer (score 9):

I've tried to simplify your code to its logical skeleton. I hope this will work and you can start adding styling and etc.

```
export default class LoginButton extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: false
  };

  doSignup = async () => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    await asyncSignupFunction();
    this.setState({ isLoading: false })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.doSignup}>
          <Text>Sign Up Now</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <ActivityIndicator animating={this.state.isLoading} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Issue is with the position of ActivityIndicator.

Try removing styling of the Container View, loader will be visible.

```
  <View>
     <ActivityIndicator animating={this.state.showLoader} size="small" 
        color="#00ff00" />
   </View>
```

Comment: Absolutely right. Indicator is placed under the violet background. Simply put 'transparent' for Text bg and you will see ActivityIndicator.

Comment: I don't think it's because of the styling, because if I put the animating as true by default, the loader will be shown.

Answer (score 4):

I am not against other answers but I am not in favour of other answers approach.

**Why I am not impressed** :

Suppose we have 6 screen so according to other answers approach I have to handle my loader in all 6 screens , when we can handle it globally why to go after each screens(`which was I am doing from last one year`).

**My new approach** :

```
npm i react-native-loading-spinner-overlay
```

Create AppLoader.js

```html
import React from 'react';
import Spinner from 'react-native-loading-spinner-overlay';
export const loaderRef = React.createRef();

export function showLoader() {
    let ref = loaderRef.current
    if (ref) {
        ref.showLoader()
    }
}

export function hideLoader() {
    let ref = loaderRef.current
    if (ref) {
        ref.hideLoader()
    }
}

class AppLoader extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { loader: false }
    }

    showLoader() {
        this.setState({ loader: true })
    }

    hideLoader() {
        this.setState({ loader: false })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Spinner visible={this.state.loader} />
        );
    }
};

export default AppLoader
```

and inside your App.js

```html
import AppLoader, { loaderRef } from 'path of AppLoader.js';

render(){
return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <AppLoader ref={loaderRef} />
        </View>
  );
}
```

**How to use it** :

```
import { showLoader, hideLoader } from 'path of Appoader.js';
```

now you can easily use `showLoader()` and `hideLoader()` function without dealing state and loader handling.

Comment: This is a very elegant  solution. The only thing I can't get to work is that I can't figure out how to implement the View. the App.js has Navigation Stack and screen and don't want to see Views in there. The Login page has KeyboardAvoidingView and adding a view inside that seems to cause a padding shift, even if the loader view is not visible.

Comment: You can use `<AppLoader ref={loaderRef} />` in `<NavigationContainer>...</NavigationContainer>`. Outside other `Navigator`.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some corrections to your existing code.

I'm mentioning some key changes here:

1. View structure
2. Position in activity indicator view

   ```
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.doSignup = this.doSignup.bind(this);
     this.state = {
       showLoader:false
     }
   }
     showLoader = () => { this.setState({ showLoader:true }); };
     hideLoader = () => { this.setState({ showLoader:false }); };

    doSignup(){
      this.showLoader();
    }
   render() {
     return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
           <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 25 }} onPress={this.doSignup}>
             <View style={[ styles.button, { backgroundColor: '#5a0060' } ]}>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, color: "white" }}>Sign Up Now</Text>
           </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>

       <View style={{ position: 'absolute', top:"50%",right: 0, left: 0 }}>
         <ActivityIndicator animating={this.state.showLoader} size="large" color="red" />
       </View>
   </View>
     );
    }
   ```

Comment: Could you explain why you've added the `constructor()` method?