# Give ref to functional component to use inner functions

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, create-ref

I have a Component let's say:

ParenComp.js

```
const ParentComp = (props) => {
  const [isTrue, setIsTrue] = useState(false);
  const setToTrue = () => {
    setIsTrue(true);
  };
  const setToFalse = () => {
    setIsTrue(false);
  };
  return isTrue ? (
  
      <Text >
        This is True
      </Text>
    
  ) : (
       <Text >
        This is False
      </Text>
  );
};
export default ParentComp;
```

**Main Question**

How can I use the `setToTrue` and `setToFalse` function in other functional component in any other file for example (Login.js)?

**What I tried**

I want to use the inner functions in another file, I know I **can not** export the functions like this:

> export const setToTrue = () => {
> setIsTrue(true);
> };

^ This is invalid

But what I was trying to do is (in ParentComp.js) create a reference using createRef, export it and create and export two functions that call the inside functions like this:

```
export const trueRef = React.createRef();
export function setToTrue() {
  let ref = trueRef.current;
  if (ref) {
    ref.setToTrue();
  }
}

export function setToFalse() {
  let ref = trueRef.current;
  if (ref) {
    ref.setToFalse();
  }
}
```

Now when I want to use this in my (Login.js). This is what I do:

```
const Login = ({ navigation }) => {
return (
<View>
<ParentComp ref={trueRef}/>
</View>
)
}
```

But the problem is, ref is not being passed to ParentComp here

> `<ParentComp ref={trueRef}/>`

So, without using **CLass Components**, how can I pass ref to my functional component to utilize the functions inside it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68642060/trigger-child-function-from-parent-component-using-react-hooks/68642839#68642839

Comment: What you're trying to do is bad practice even if it's possible.

Comment: @technophyle , can you elaborate why it is a bad practice?

What I will achieve from this is that I will just have to use the functions to set the state, and not manage state in other files. Take the above ParentComp as a Loader. I won't have to set state on everything. I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61840866/14267431) answer, and turning it into functional component.

Comment: It's bad practice because React says it is. React components are supposed to be self-contained modules of logic and behavior. React components don't reach into other React components and pull strings, i.e. call functions, etc. The `useImperativeHandle` is essentially a backdoor for odd/obscure use cases. Similar to the Class component's [forceUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate), it's an escape hatch. Generally if you need to force things you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Because it should be your last resort to call another component's inner function. What you want to do can be simply done by passing a prop instead.

Comment: Thankyou for your feedback Drew Reese and technophyle , but @technophyle would I be able to achieve the above by passing props, I will have to manage state in every file where I want to use them? Am I wrong?

If I am, please can you give me your side of answer, I will be thankful.

Comment: True but if you don't use a prop, you have to add a context objects as well.

Comment: See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). The idea is that the state and handlers are declared in a common ancestor component and the state/handlers passed down as props or in a Context to the component that you want to trigger updates.

Comment: @DrewReese, I now understand why it is a bad practice. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) hook with [ref forwarding](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components) to give an external component access to the methods.

As noted by @technophyle and @Drew Reese in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75106025/give-ref-to-functional-component-to-use-inner-functions/75106182#comment132538836_75106025), `useImperativeHandle` is an escape hatch that is usually used in specific cases that require direct access to a DOM node. For example, focusing an input, or scrolling to an element.

Example:

```js
const { forwardRef, useState, useImperativeHandle, useRef } = React;

const ParentComp = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [isTrue, setIsTrue] = useState(false);
  const setToTrue = () => { setIsTrue(true); };
  const setToFalse = () => { setIsTrue(false); };
  
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    setToTrue,
    setToFalse
  }));
  
  return (
    <div>This is {isTrue ? 'True' : 'False'}</div>
  );
});

const Login = () => {
  const trueRef = useRef();
  
  return (
    <div>
      <ParentComp ref={trueRef}/>
      <button onClick={() => trueRef.current.setToTrue()}>True</button>
      <button onClick={() => trueRef.current.setToFalse()}>False</button>
    </div>
  );
};
  
ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Login />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

A better way to reuse the logic, is to create a custom hook that encapsulates the behavior and use it in `Login`:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const useIsTrue = () => {
  const [isTrue, setIsTrue] = useState(false);
  
  return {
    setToTrue() { setIsTrue(true); },
    setToFalse() { setIsTrue(false); },
    isTrue
  };
}

const ParentComp = ({ isTrue }) => (
  <div>This is {isTrue ? 'True' : 'False'}</div>
);

const Login = () => {
  const { setToTrue, setToFalse, isTrue } = useIsTrue();
  
  return (
    <div>
      <ParentComp isTrue={isTrue}/>
      <button onClick={setToTrue}>True</button>
      <button onClick={setToFalse}>False</button>
    </div>
  );
};
  
ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Login />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Great solution! especially the second one <3